# server client socket programming output difficulties

Tags: java

m new in socket programming...i hv to create a server that stores name & id from a client in a queue and then it stores all the inputs given by the client in another queue.  when the client writes 'test', server retrieves all the stored data as the client types some value i.e. integer...when client types 'resume' server again starts storing client's given input in the queue...if client types 'exit' server sends back the client's name and id and starts waiting for a ne client. And the receives those info and closes the socket.

**Problem faced:**
m facing problem in retrieving the data from queues. when i type exit, i can see the name and id which i'm retriving through the for loop. if i put this line outToClient.writeBytes("Thank You!"+'\n'); after the for loop then it shows the client's name & id but the client doest go off.

in the if else condition while checking for 'test' again i'm facing problem in retrieving data. server asks for integer..client types an integer and then i dont get the data from server.

**here is my code**

**Server Side:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class server
{
  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
 String clientSentence;
 String replySentence;
 ServerSocket welcomeSocket= new ServerSocket(6789);

while(true)
{
System.out.println("#########Server Waiting#########");
Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));          
DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

Queue<String> qe = new LinkedList<String>();

outToClient.writeBytes("Enter your Name and ID Please..."+'\n');
for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
{
 clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
 qe.add(clientSentence); 
}

outToClient.writeBytes("Thank you! You may now proceed further..."+'\n'); 

Queue<String> chatq = new LinkedList<String>();
clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

while(!clientSentence.equals("exit"))
{

  if(clientSentence.equals("test"))
  {
    outToClient.writeBytes("Enter Integers to fetch data or 'resume' to continue..."+'\n');
    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

    while(!clientSentence.equals("resume"))
    {
        replySentence = chatq.remove();
        outToClient.writeBytes(replySentence+'\n');
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
    }

    if(clientSentence.equals("resume"))
    {
      outToClient.writeBytes("You may now proceed again..."+'\n');
      clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

    } 
  }

  else
  {
    chatq.add(clientSentence);
    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
  }        

}

if(clientSentence.equals("exit"))
{
  outToClient.writeBytes("Client Name & ID: "+'\n');

 for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
  {
    replySentence = qe.remove();
    outToClient.writeBytes(replySentence+'\n');
  } 


}  
} 
}
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class client
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
   {
   String sentence;
   String modifiedSentence;

   BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   InetAddress inetAddress=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   System.out.println(inetAddress);

   Socket clientSocket = new Socket(inetAddress,6789);
   while(true)
   {

      DataOutputStream outToServer =  new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());       

      BufferedReader inFromServer = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

      modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine();
      System.out.println("From Server: "+modifiedSentence+'\n');

      for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
      {
       sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence+'\n');   
      }
       modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine();
       System.out.println("From Server: "+modifiedSentence + '\n');



        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
         while(!sentence.equals("exit"))
         {

if(sentence.equals("test"))
{
  outToServer.writeBytes(sentence+'\n');
  modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine();
  System.out.println("From Server: "+modifiedSentence + '\n');
  sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

  while(!sentence.equals("resume"))
  {
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence+'\n');
    modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("From Server: "+modifiedSentence + '\n');
    sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
  }

  if(sentence.equals("resume"))
  {
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence+'\n');
    modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("From Server: "+modifiedSentence + '\n');
    sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

  }

}

else
{
  outToServer.writeBytes(sentence+'\n');
  sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
 }
}

  if(sentence.equals("exit"))
  {
  outToServer.writeBytes(sentence+'\n');
  modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine();
  System.out.println("From Server: "+modifiedSentence + '\n');
  for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
  {
    modifiedSentence=inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println(modifiedSentence + '\n');
  } 

  clientSocket.close(); 
  break;
}

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is `[homework]` however...

You are mixing binary (DataOutputStream) with text (BufferedReader).  You should use one or the other or you are bound to confuse yourself.

It appears you want to send text so I would use BufferedReader and PrintWriter. DataOutputStream is better suited for binary protocols.

Comment: yea...this is homework n m trying to do it...m not good at java so having difficulties....m gonna try with PrintWriter n let u know..thnx

Comment: i've only replaced the dataoutputstream with PrintWriter like this: PrintWriter outToClient = null; outToClient = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), true); and data printing places like :  outToClient.println("Thank you! You may now proceed further..."+'\n'); 
           now m a bit moer confused as outputs are not coming as it were...can u plz xplain a bit or may b refer any useful link? m checking some but still i'd appreciate if u help

Comment: Can you use English rather than text speak? Can you update your code in the question with what you have now?

Comment: sorry about the text speech. i've updated the code now. i was writing outToClient.writeBytes(replySentence); instead of outToClient.writeBytes(replySentence+'\n'); i madee this change and it's working. now i'll have to make sure that the client can only give integers after typing 'test'.

Comment: I told you not to use DataOutputStream and use PrintWriter instead. Can you update you code to reflect this?

Comment: sure..right after i am done with the integer checking i will update my code using PrintWriter